# Date and conditions using PL/SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I am having a problem with the procedure below as whenever I pass a date of month and year, the IF condition loops on the number of records that exists in my table- only two rows existed- and also it shows the two possibilities. I also included the result to show what I mean!

```
 PRODUCT_NUM   ORDER_NUM    QUANTITY        PRICE     MONTHLY_DATE
-------------- ----------- ------------- ------------ -------------
   12345         106           3             19.99     21-DEC-15   
   67894         107           1             19.99     21-DEC-15


 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proce_Name (Pram_Date DATE ) 
   AS
 BGIN
  FOR Y IN 
    (SELECT SUM(PRICE) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT, SUM(NVL(QUANTITY,0) * NVL (   
    (PRICE,0)) AS TOTAL, MONTHLY_DATE   
    FROM PRODUCTS
    GROUP BY MONTHLY_DATE 
    ORDER BY MONTHLY_DATE DESC) LOOP
    IF  TO_CHAR( Y.MONTHLY_DATE, 'mm-yyyy')= TO_CHAR(Pram_Date,'mm-yyyy') THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL AMOUNT: '|| '  '|| Y.TOTAL_AMOUNT);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL: '|| '   '||  Y.TOTAL);
   ELSE
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Data for this month');
   END IF;
  END LOOP;

END Proce_name;
```

calling block:

```
DECLARE
   MONTHLY_D DATE := TO_DATE('01-2012','mm-yyyy');
BEGIN
 Proce_Name(MONTHLY_D);
END;
```

/

This is when the date I pass matches the records in the table:

```
     No Data for this month

     TOTAL AMOUNT:   4

     TOTAL:      99.96
```

The result here when I pass a date that is not existed in the table:

```
     No Data for this month
     No Data for this month
```

How can I alter my procedure to examine the above date format accurately ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have update procedure as following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_sales_report(c_date date) AS
  l_amount number(18, 2);
  l_total  number(18, 2);
BEGIN
  begin
    SELECT SUM(PRICE), SUM(NVL(QUANTITY, 0) * NVL(PRICE, 0))
      into l_amount, l_total
      FROM product
     where TO_CHAR(MONTHLY_DATE, 'mm-yyyy') = to_char(c_date, 'mm-yyyy')
     GROUP BY TO_CHAR(MONTHLY_DATE, 'mm-yyyy')
     ORDER BY TO_CHAR(MONTHLY_DATE, 'mm-yyyy') DESC;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL AMOUNT: ' || '  ' || l_amount);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL: ' || '   ' || l_total);
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Data for this month');
  END; -- end of exception
  -- add your code here
  -- add your code here
  -- add your code here
end;
```

Also call following command for dbms_output echoing text.

```
set serveroutput on size 30000;
```

Call your procedure as

```
declare
  c_date2 DATE := TO_DATE('12-2015','mm-yyyy');
begin
  get_sales_report(c_date2);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, still have the save problem !!

Comment: Can you post create statement of PRODUCTS table and post the code snippet you use to call Proce_Name  procedure?

Comment: Please have a look at the question

Comment: Ok. According to you test data, my suggested code block should do fine. Please note that; I have made changes in select statement, order by and group by. Can you post the output after running my code block.

Comment: This is copy/ paste of the result - No sales in this date
No sales in this date

Comment: I have updated my answer, it is tested and working. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Thank you faith for your reply. I have alter according to your update, but this is what I got anonymous block completed
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Comment: You are welcome; did you make the call as `get_sales_report('12-2015');` I have changed input type to varchar from date. I also suggest copy/paste whole code between `create` and `end procedure`

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. The only problem in the procedure is when a user a date that is not existed in the table. So the condition should test that dates resides in the table! Prior to your last comment, I did make the call to exec get_sales_report('12-2015'); and got that error! I also altered the c_date as varchar as shown in your answer earlier!

Comment: Could I ask why the TO_CHAR( Y.MONTHLY_DATE, 'mm-yyyy')= TO_CHAR(Pram_Date,'mm-yyyy') does not work properly inside the for loop?

Comment: After re-examining your code, the problem in your code is group by statement is not correct. It groups by `day` only.

Comment: I have re-updated script to accept date input variable, it works.

Comment: I have removed group by and the result was SQL Error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function", How do I get away of this error?

Comment: you should not remove group by it should stay as `GROUP BY TO_CHAR( MONTHLY_DATE, 'mm-yyyy')`

Comment: If you are satisfied with the solution please mark it "as answered".

Comment: It did work, but it looped twice!! The result saying: No Data for this month. This is based on the number of the records in the table. If I have more than two rows, let's say 10, would the condition loops 10 saying No Data for this month? This was basically my question

Comment: it will print `No data ...` line  until you add the date condition to where statement. 
` ...
FROM product
        where TO_CHAR( MONTHLY_DATE, 'mm-yyyy') = to_char(c_date, 'mm-yyyy')
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR( MONTHLY_DATE, 'mm-yyyy') 
.... `

Comment: I am so sorry for taking up your time, but is there any way I could stop the repetition of no data ... output and to be displayed only once when the condition is not achieved?

Comment: I'have changed your code, I removed loop because you do not need one(you already sum the values) and added exception block (it is the only way) . Give it a try it is working.

Comment: I removed the for loop  and also added  d_month ,l_amount and l_total and then put this line IF D_MONTH = TO_CHAR(c_date,'mm-yyyy') THEN but i had this error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: It worked perfectly cheers. However, the No data found blocked the rest of the sales report results! In this case only the NO_DATA_FOUND would work but can't use if ? Sorry again

Comment: I just updated procedure and added begin end statement, add your additional sales report code after the line ` END; -- end of exception` . And also please mark as answered.

Comment: Thank you again your answer. Fatihn I have this procedure with many cursors I created for my sale report. When I do the no_data_found, it kinda block every cursor I have! For example, I can't get the records for the deleted or cancelled items, highest number of sales etc. The no_data_found is a good mechanism but my intention is SELECT
 if monthy =to_char(c_date,'mm-yyyy') then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL AMOUNT: ' || '  ' || l_amount);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL: ' || '   ' || l_total);
  else 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Data for this month');

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, you can consider exception handling as well:
Few observations, you an consider prem_date as char it self instead of passing date. Also if data set is huge and monthly_date is indexed, you should avoid applying to_char condition on monthly_date.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proce_Name (Pram_Date DATE )
   AS
  l_total_amount float;
  l_total float;
 BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(PRICE) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT,
     SUM(NVL(QUANTITY,0) * NVL(PRICE,0)) AS TOTAL
    INTO l_total_amount, l_total
    FROM PRODUCTS
    WHERE to_char(monthly_date, 'mm-yyyy') = to_char(pram_date, 'mm-yyyy');
    if(l_total_amount is not null) then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL AMOUNT: '|| '  '|| L_TOTAL_AMOUNT);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL: '|| '   '||  L_TOTAL);
    else
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Data for this month');
    end if;
END Proce_name;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the condition does not work in the procedure! And also I have more than one result so the loop is needed!

Answer (score 0):

Dates are fixed sized types. So, if you want to group by a whole month, you must query your date column as char. Meaning, you should use TO_CHAR instead of TO_DATE.

Here's (the simpler) way to do it (My changes are lowercase) -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proce_Name (Pram_Date date) AS   
  l_month        char(7);
  l_total_amount number;
  l_total        number;
BEGIN
  SELECT to_char(monthly_date,'mm-yyyy') as month, 
          SUM(PRICE) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT, 
          SUM(NVL(QUANTITY,0)*NVL(PRICE,0)) AS TOTAL   
   INTO l_month, l_total_amount, l_total
   FROM PRODUCTS
   where to_char(monthly_date,'mm-yyyy')=to_char(Pram_Date, 'mm-yyyy')
   GROUP BY to_char(monthly_date,'mm-yyyy');

  if l_month is not null then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL AMOUNT: '|| '  '|| Y.TOTAL_AMOUNT);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOTAL: '|| '   '||  Y.TOTAL);  
  else
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No Data for this month');
  end if;   

END Proce_name;
/
```

Here's some testing code - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1068/2

Comment: I have done my query to TO_char, but I need to examine the date as it passed to the procedure. Meaning if the Monthly_date exist then show the result. However, if the date is not existed display a message of no data for this month. I don't want to use the EXCEPTION as this is one procedure from many. So I have individual results out the same date!

Comment: Using EXCEPTION is just cleaner code, but you don't have to really. You can do it like you did it, with an IF ELSE. Still, there is no way to avoid TO_CHAR. if you need the Pram_Date to be of type DATE, that's ok, just pass it as a date and cast it implicitly within your select.. It would look something like this - 
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proce_Name (Pram_Date date)
 AS  
 BEGIN
  ...
 SELECT ... WHERE to_char(monthly_date,'mm-yyyy') = to_char(Pram_Date,'mm-yyyy')
 ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you alter the code based on your comment please?

Comment: Done. couldn't test it though as fiddle was down. Should work. If it does, an upvote would be much appreciated :)